# HTML/Javascript Only 3 Range Sliders, Sum to 100, 2 Separate Math Interactions

Tags: javascript, html, math, slider

**Updated.**

Sean Kaat put me in the right direction on how to add input fields. However, I am still unsure of how to do the math relationships between the three ranges.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
<head>
<meta charset='UTF-8'>
</head>

<title>Calculator</title>
<h1>Calculator</h1>

<body>

<form>
<Label for="sliderBarOne">Ready</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarOne" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" oninput="this.form.rangeOne.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeOne" oninput="this.form.sliderBarOne.value=this.value, updateSum();">
<br>
<Label for="sliderBarTwo">ACW</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarTwo" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" oninput="this.form.rangeTwo.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeTwo" oninput="this.form.sliderBarTwo.value=this.value">
<br>
<Label for="sliderBarThree">Extra</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarThree" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" oninput="this.form.rangeThree.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeThree" oninput="this.form.sliderBarThree.value=this.value">
<br>Sum: <span id="sum">0</span>
</form>

<script>

document.getElementById("sliderBarOne").addEventListener("input", updateReady);
document.getElementById("sliderBarTwo").addEventListener("input", updateACW);
document.getElementById("sliderBarThree").addEventListener("input", updateExtra);

function updateReady() {
  let readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne').value;
  let ACWBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo').value; 
  let extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree').value;

  updateSum();
}

function updateACW() {
  let readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne').value;
  let ACWBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo').value; 
  let extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree').value; 

  updateSum();
}

function updateExtra() {
  let readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne').value;
  let ACWBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo').value; 
  let extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree').value; 

  updateSum();
}

function updateSum() {
  var sliderOneValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarOne').value;
  var sliderTwoValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo').value;
  var sliderThreeValue = +document.getElementById('sliderBarThree').value;
  document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sliderOneValue + sliderTwoValue + sliderThreeValue;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to make two separate math relationships that I am unaware of how to even start working on.

I want Ready to be the first number set with ACW being set to 100-Ready.  So, if there is 95 Ready, ACW is automatically set to 5. I want Extra to be set to 0 to start.

```
Ready = 95.00
ACW = 5.00
Extra = 0.00
```

So, to demonstrate the impact of Extra Time on Ready and ACW, I want any addition of Extra to adjust both Ready and ACW, while keeping Ready and ACW = 100.  Ready + ACW + Extra does not equal 100.

So, the following would occur with Extra inputted at 5.00.

```
Ready = 90.00
ACW = 10.00
Extra = 5.00
```

Sean Kaat suggested something that isn't working for me right now, and I don't know why. I have the empty functions of updateReady, updateACW and updateExtra set so that I can use it to handle the three separate mathematical changes.

Comment: I just realized that what I'm looking for is actually a bit broken.  90+5+10 != 100.  Ugh.  Basically, I want Ready + Extra to be locked to 100 with ACW being independent of the 100 constraint, but still adding the value coming from Extra.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the math amount is going to substantially increase; you want to be sure to set the values in a specific order.

First: set READY equal to `PREVIOUS_READY_VALUE - EXTRA` (and if the value is below 0, just set it to 0),

Then: set ACW equal to `100 - (EXTRA + READY)`,

Finally: set the `input.value` of each slider to the above values

Each `onChange` event of the sliders should do the math and then change the values of the html accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Sean.  Can I get a small headstart on the code?  I'm still super new and am unsure how to get started on setting the initial values.

Comment: Sure: to get the input box use: `let inputBox = document.getElementById([classNameString])` and then to access/set the number value of the slider, use: `inputBox.value = numberToSet`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I appreciate it.

Comment: `function getValues() { 
    let readyBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarOne'); 
    let ACWBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarTwo'); 
    let extraBox = document.getElementById('sliderBarThree'); 

    let _ready = readyBox.value - extraBox.value;
    if (_ready < 0) {
        _ready = 0;
    }
    let _ACW = 100 - (extraBox.value + readyBox.value);

    readyBox.value = _ready;
    ACWBox.value = _ACW;
}`

Comment: Thanks!  I have the input fields working now, along with still summing them all.

<Label for="sliderBarThree">Extra</Label>
<input type="range" id="sliderBarThree" min="0" max="100" step="0.01" value="0" oninput="this.form.rangeThree.value=this.value">
<input type="number" id="rangeThree" oninput="this.form.sliderBarThree.value=this.value">
<br>Sum: <span id="sum">0</span>

document.getElementById("sliderBarOne").addEventListener("input", updateSum);

Comment: Sean, I updated the question with the latest code.  Still can't figure out how to resolve this issue.  If I try to use your code, it doesn't constrain correctly.

Comment: onchange and parseFloat solved a bunch of my problems.  I have it done!